# How to design an edit template for parent model such that a new child model can also be created using CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, parent-child, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.1.  A Parent hasMany Children, but also has a favourite Child.  (So there is a field called `Parent.favourite_child` is set to `Child.id` of one of its Children, or is `null`.)  The models and basic templates are all working fine.

On the edit page (template) for Parent I am able to edit the details of the currently selected FavouriteChild for this Parent (using FavouriteChild.id, etc).  However, I want to make the page more dynamic (by adding either Ajax or Javascript) to do the following: give the user to be able to Select one of the other Children as the favourite, and then edit that Childs details, or to select "new" for the current Favourite Child which should bring up a blank details for a (yet-to-be-created) new Child, and edit those details.

(Another example of this problem would be the case when a Thing hasMany Versions, but only one version is the `active` version.)

I am not sure how to approach this.  It seems that this would be a common use-case.  There are several approaches I have considered:

1. The Parent edit page has two distinct forms on the same
   `parent/edit/1` page (one for Parent, one for Child) and then load
   the Child fields upon changes ("onchange") from the select list in
   Parent form;
2. The Parent edit Page has only one form for Parent, but includes
   fields for Child as well;
3. Using ajax in the Child form.

(I have no experience yet including JavaScript, or Ajax calls, so advice on that would be helpful if it is suggested in your answer.)

I was thinking that some javascript like the examples given at this site would be the approach to dynamically load one of the current favourite children:
[Dynamic web coding](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/paired.php)

EDIT
This helped with the "dynamic" aspect of the question.  I simply update the form immediately on any change to the Parent fields.  (Still haven't decided if I will use two forms (one for Parent, one for Fav Child) or only one for Parent where the FavChild fields are loaded onto the parent, e.g. parent.favorite_child.child_name, etc.)

Here is the simple change to Form input:

```
        echo $this->Form->input('recyclable', [
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'onChange' => 'this.form.submit()'
        ]);
```

For the select dropdown it is, similarly, just adding the 'onChange' option to it as well.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your `Parent` model (Table)? It would be easier to provide something with it without making assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **What you need**

1. Relation To Regular children and Favorited children in the Parent
   model
2. The entity of the Parent in a form for example
3. A list of all the children available for
       favoritism.

> Relation To Regular children and Favorited children in the Parent
>       model

Set up relation to the Children table with the relation hasOne / hasMany 
depending on if you want to have one regular child per parent or many.

Do this for both the Children and the FavoritedChildren they use the same table, so you can write it like this:

```
$this->hasMany('Children');

$this->hasMany('FavoritedChildren', ['className' => 'Children']);
```

In the Childrens model set the relations to `belongsTo();`

> The entity of the Parent in a form for example

Create your controller method and view following CakePHP naming conventions.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

```
$this->Form->create($parentEntity);
```

add your input fields, if you want to save associated data use the indexes of your associated Childrens model like this:

'**Children.name**', '**FavoritedChildren.name**'

Input should be generated like this:

```
$this->Form->input('FavoritedChildren.name');
```

Once your form is correctly set up, you're able to save the parent entity with the association to your child, if it contains Favorited data or not.

```
$parent = $this->Parents->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => ['FavoritedChildren']
]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations

> A list of all the children available for favoritism

This is needed to select the child. In your controller method, just find a list of all the children you want to choose from

```
$availableChildren = $this->Childrens->find('list');
$this->set(compact('availableChildren'));
```

And use the `$availableChildren` variable in your View with an Input select or however you want to select the children.

```
$this->Form->input('Children.id', ['options' => $availableChildren]);
$this->Form->input('FavoritedChildren.id', ['options' => $availableChildren]);
```

Hope this answer were some help to you.

Comment: Thanks JazzCat.  I have the stuff you mention working.  I have no problem loading the Parent's data and the associated Child data, and no problem accessing the fields of the Children, (including a `FavoriteChild'). The guidance I am looking for is the mechanics of designing the UI of the edit page.  I want to be able to change the favorite child to an existing child (and edit those Child details), or change the favorite child to a new child and input those fields and create the new child (and set this new child to the current favorite.)

Comment: Then you should make an ajax call when you're selecting that child in for example a select list. For new children, simply display from the list variable, for already related children select from the associated data. The function you're calling could return a viewblock or json data that you could display in the view components. And then run the associated save function when posting the new form with the favoritechild.